# Запуск приложения в фоне.

Tags: android

Необходимо запустить GoogleVoice в фоне при старте приложения. Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: а что хочется сделать? Если приложение не умеет работать в фоне, то без хаков вы его там работать не заставите.

Comment: чтобы при `onStart()` запускалось приложение и одновременно в фоне GoogleVoice. можно обратиться через `Intent`, но тогда фокус уйдет от приложения к GoogleVoice. а нужно, чтобы просто стартануло и висело в памяти.

Comment: понятно, что через `Service`, но как организовать запуск приложения?

Comment: а какой смысл в том, что оно будет висеть в фоне? оптимизация скорости загрузки?

Comment: именно она.

Comment: учитывая, что андроид может прибить приложение в любой момент (практически), а приложение в фоне ещё чаще, то эта оптимизация может только усугубить ситуацию.

Comment: и через сервис оказывается запустить нельзя.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Упрощенно так:

```
RecognitionListener recognitionListener = new CustomRecognitionListener();
SpeechRecognizer speechRecognizer = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(context);

speechRecognizer.setRecognitionListener(recognitionListener);

Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
// TODO: ...
```

где

```
class CustomRecognitionListener implements RecognitionListener {
    // TODO: ...
}
```

Подробнее смотреть, например, здесь: [VoiceInput.java](http://www.google.com/codesearch#3aMARKchqsQ/trunk/ime/latinime/src/com/googlecode/eyesfree/inputmethod/voice/VoiceInput.java&q=googlevoice&type=cs).